# Probability of 4 people having birthday at same day and hour?

Tags: probability

I am reading "introduction to probability 2nd edition" by Joseph K. and Blitzstein.    A problem is to

> (b) With assumptions as in (a), what is the probability that there are
>   four sophomores who were born not only on the same day, but also at
>   the same hour (e.g., all were born between 2 pm and 3 pm on March 31,
>   not necessarily in the same year)?

(the assumptions in a) was those as in the birthday problem - independent birthdays with equal probability). Also, there are n = 1600 sophomores.

Then they state that the solution to this problem is as follows:

> Now there are b = 365·24 = 8760 categories. Let’s explore two
>   different methods of Poisson approximation.
>
> Create an indicator for each set of 4 sophomores. By linearity, the
>   expected number of sets of 4 sophomores born on the same day-hour is
>
> $$ \lambda_1 = \binom{n}{4}\frac{1}{b^3} $$ Poisson approximation
>   gives that the desired probability is approximately $$
> > 1-exp(-\lambda_1) \simeq 0.333 $$

Now I get that the binomial coefficient should be $\binom{n}{4}$. However, I have solved a similar problem before and the result I got, together with my understand of probability in general, leads me to the question: Why $\frac{1}{b^3}$ and not $\frac{1}{b}$?

Comment: Of course! Just updated my post :)

Comment: I suspect they may have started with $b\cdot{n\choose 4}\frac{(b-1)^{b-4}}{b^b}$

Comment: @Henry They did not. I have cited everything there is stated in their solution derivation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A factor of "$1/b$" for each additional person after the first.  If all you have is "$1/b$" there are only two people in the same category.  If you have $(1/b)^3$, there are four people in the same category.  (What about the first person?  The first person is always in the same category as the first person.)

Suppose there were only two categories and we want four people in the same bin.  The first person is in whichever bin.  The probability for each of the remaining $3$ being in that same bin is $1/2$ each.  This results in a $(1/2)^3 = 1/8$ probability that all three land in the same bin as the first person.